# Access Resources In Dynamic Feature Module of App Bundle

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

My usage scenario is a bit complicated.

In the dynamic form, I only have some views and resources. Those views should have access to those resources. In my base module, I will use these views from the activity of a basic module. Both my application and activity replace the attachBaseContext method.

But when I download and install the dynamic form, my views can not access resources using the task context. However, resources are accessible from applicationContext.

I do not understand how SplitCompat works. So the classes and resources loaded by the dynamic module connect only to applicationContext?

Comment: The question is very generic and I cannot understand what you mean with task context.

Comment: My main problem is that after I request and install the dynamic module, my app cannot find the resources in the dynamic module. And it turned out to be a bug of Android Studio...Just invalidate the cache and clean the project and try again...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably caused by an Android Studio bug. Clean the project and invalidate the cache, or build the project again.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at how Dynamic Features are implemented in [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features).

There's sample code on how to open some resources, located in a dynamic module, [from the base module](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/samples/dynamicfeatures/MainActivity.kt#L151).

Plus, the samples includes others dynamic modules with activities in implemented in Java/Kotlin and native.

Comment: I had looked into this demo many times before I actually try app bundle myself... This is a rather simple demo with only accessing some isolated activity and resources, not quite the same use case as mine...